# How to print two rectangles on the same line

Tags: python

I've been given a task in which I've managed to write an function to print a rectangle based of a given input.

```
int1 = int(input("Give me a number: "))

def rectangle(n, m) :
             
    for i in range(1, n+1) :
        for j in range(1, m+1) :
            if ( i == 1 or i == n or
                j == 1 or j == m ) :
                print("*", end="") 
            else :
                print(" ", end="")           
         
        print()
 
rows = int1 
columns = (int1*2)+0
rectangle(rows, columns)
```

The function works as follows:

```
input:
Give me a number: 3

output:
******
*    *
******

input: 
Give me a number: 4

output:
******** 
*      *
*      *
********
```

I'm trying to print, instead of just one rectangle when an input is given, but two on the same line with a space in between like so;

```
input: 
Give me a number: 4

output:
******** ******** 
*      * *      *
*      * *      *
******** ********
```

Any advice or guidance would be great, I know I could iterate the for loop to extend two squares on the same line within one function and miss out the middle and middle+1 columns to make it seem like two squares but have been unsuccesful.

Comment: Do you need that period between the two rectangles?

Comment: I've ammended, no I did not.

Comment: Have you made any effort towards solving the problem? If so, posting that will be very helpful in getting more people to help out.

Comment: I did, next time I will record what I have attempted to do. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest if you make the rectangle function return the string, not print it!

```
def rectangle(n, m):
    r = ["*" * m]
    for _ in range(n-2):
        r.append("*" + " " * (m-2) + "*")
    r.append("*" * m)
    return "\n".join(r)

>>> print(rectangle(4, 5))
*****
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Now you can reuse the single rectangle function to get rectangles side by side by splitting into lines and processing the lines:

```
def xrectangles(n, m, x):
    r = rectangle(n, m).splitlines()
    return "\n".join("  ".join([row] * x) for row in r)
    
>>> print(xrectangles(4, 5, 3))
*****  *****  *****
*   *  *   *  *   *
*   *  *   *  *   *
*****  *****  *****

>>> print(xrectangles(3, 3, 7))
***  ***  ***  ***  ***  ***  ***
* *  * *  * *  * *  * *  * *  * *
***  ***  ***  ***  ***  ***  ***
```

Comment: Great solution. I didn't think of that!